# How do I set up a adjacency list with an association object with SQLAlchemy?

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, adjacency-list

I am trying to create a database model where you can have a bunch of products that could be part of other products and also contain other products. I have figured out how to do this like this:

```
product_to_product = Table(
    "product_to_product",
    Base.metadata,
    Column("id", Integer, primary_key=True),
    Column("parent_id", Integer, ForeignKey("products.id")),
    Column("child_id", Integer, ForeignKey("products.id")),
)


class Product(Base):
    __tablename__ = "products"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    parents = relationship(
        "Product",
        secondary=product_to_product,
        primaryjoin=id == product_to_product.c.parent_id,
        secondaryjoin=id == product_to_product.c.child_id,
        backref="children",
    )
```

This lets me add products like this:

```
root = Product()

parent1 = Product()
parent2 = Product()

child1 = Product()
child2 = Product()
child3 = Product()

root.children = [parent1, parent2]
parent1.children = [child1, child2, child3]
parent2.children = [child1, child2]
```

I can then grab all the products and the links between parents/children work exactly as I want.

Now I want to switch to using an association object to manage the link instead, because I want to have additional data. I have tried setting this up like this:

```
class ParentReference(Base):
    __tablename__ = "parent_references"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("products.id"))
    child_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("products.id"))
    additional_data = Column(String)


class Product(Base):
    __tablename__ = "products"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    parents = relationship(
        "Product",
        secondary=ParentReference,
        primaryjoin=id == ParentReference.child_id,
        secondaryjoin=id == ParentReference.parent_id,
        backref=backref("children"),
    )
```

I have found many examples that do this if the objects linked together with the many-to-many relationship are two different objects (like `User` and `Community`), but never for this case where it's the same object. My attempt is cobbled together from different examples, but it doesn't work with the script as before. I have also seen examples use `association_proxy` functions, and several other approaches, but I am not able to get this to work.

My goal is to be able to add products, link them up, and navigate them as before, but also be able to access the `ParentReference` object from a `Product` so I can grab the additional data on it. Can someone please help me figure this out?

Answer (score 0):

After some more trial and error, I figured out how to do this. Here's my solution:

```
class ParentReference(Base):
    __tablename__ = "parent_references"

    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("products.id"), primary_key=True)
    child_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey("products.id"), primary_key=True)
    extra_data = Column(String)

    parent = relationship(
        "Product",
        primaryjoin=lambda: ParentReference.child_id == Product.id,
        backref="child_references"
    )
    child = relationship(
        "Product",
        primaryjoin=lambda: ParentReference.parent_id == Product.id,
        backref="parent_references"
    )


class Product(Base):
    __tablename__ = "products"

    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)

    parents = relationship(
        "Product",
        secondary="parent_references",
        primaryjoin=lambda: Product.id == ParentReference.parent_id,
        secondaryjoin=lambda: Product.id == ParentReference.child_id,
        backref="children"
    )
```

This works like this:

```
root = Product()
parent1 = Product()
parent2 = Product()
child1 = Product()
child2 = Product()
child3 = Product()

parent1.parent_references = [
    ParentReference(parent=root, child=parent1, extra_data="Hello World!")
]
root.children.append(parent2)
parent1.children = [child1, child2, child3]
parent2.children = [child1, child2]
```

And it allows me to access parents/children, as well as the reference object and the extra data in it.